# Inconsistency in rootless mode configuration

Tags: docker

I am reading the Docker documentation regarding the configuration of [rootless mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/). I don't understand why at one point it says:

```
[INFO] Make sure the following environment variables are set (or add them to ~/.bashrc):

export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock
```

However, later on, we learn that we need to directly select a context by issuing the command:

```
docker context use rootless
```

But doing this results in a warning:

```
docker context use rootless
rootless
Current context is now "rootless"
Warning: DOCKER_HOST environment variable overrides the active context. To use "rootless", either set the global --context flag, or unset DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

So, setting the `DOCKER_HOST` variable earlier now causes an error, and the recommended solution is to perform an "`unset`" on a variable that we were previously supposed to set.

Can someone explain this to me?